# Should I use Google Maps API for creating Gaming maps?

Tags: google-maps

Hi I just want to ask about those custom Google maps that you can put on your web page, I was thinking of using them for a couple a "maps" in a game to show where certain items are on one "layer", location of destructable objects in another layer, spawn points and all that. I was wondering if the Google API can cover all these or should I make one myself?

Answer (score 1):

The layers would be conceptual (ie, the GMaps API doesn't know about layers) but yes. You can store the markers you add in your own layers array. Each member of that array would be an array of markers corresponding to each type. You can create your own custom markers, spawn them at any point in the map and so on.

The API may be too slow for a game where markers move real time, for a turn based one it's certainly possible.

What you can't do is to copy the image and redistribute it, so your game would have to run on top of Google Maps.

Comment: ahh, thanks I should of worded it correctly. It's actually a resource map to help people playing a game. So I can add tables within hotspots and display data a-okay without too much problems?

Comment: Yes. I reiterate that you cannot take a screenshot of the output and place it as a static image though, due to licensing terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Overlays or [Ground Overlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#GroundOverlays) (for map-like objects and "layers"), and [markers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers) (for item-like objects).

Comment: Would this whole process take longer than making it in Dreamweaver. It's just a click/show web map.

Comment: @PUFFY: I don't have any experience with Dreamweaver, so I can't compare =| Shouldn't take long though - load an image as the ground overlay, set sprites, done.

Comment: Those aren't actually layers in the GIS sense of the word (where you can have a polygon layer (with many polygons) or a line layer (with many lines) or a point layer (with many points) as a single unit). Don't know if the OP tried to mean layer in a GIS-sense though.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to start this for our weekend guild quests, I just happened to stumble across Google Maps API on a search and found it, hoping that it would be faster rather than making it in Dreamweaver. I have absolutely NO experience with this, just the fact that Google makes user friendly things bought me. If I were to explain the "layers" it would be like Photoshop. The base layer would just be the raw map of the game level. on top would show different things like an item layer would be circles placed on where to items are etc etc.